# How can a 777ER fly from the 9000 ft runway at Bologna (LIPE)?

Tags: runways, boeing-777

How can a 777ER be operated from the Bologna runway which is only 9000ft?

I recently took the Emirates flight and the aircraft was full. I suppose that it was close to max weight. According to wiki the required runway at max load is 10000ft so what is the trick behind this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LIPE - OMDB is only around 4,500 KM (2,800 NM) according to [Great Circle Mapper](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LIPE-OMDB&PM=b%3Adisc7&MS=wls&DU=mi), which is nowhere close to the 773ER max range of 14,500 KM (7,830 NM), so one can make an educated guess that the aircraft wasn't at MTOW.

Comment: Was actually thinking about it. Just needed some confirmation. So probably they would reduce the fuel load?

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni For sure.

Comment: Every airline flight is done with minimum fuel these days. Any  extra fuel costs money in additional fuel burned in order to carry the extra weight of fuel that is not needed to complete the flight.